# passing concurrentdictionary to another method

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I'm facing some problem in passing ConcurrentDictionary to another method with an out parameter.

In main method,

```
Method1(1,2,dictionary);

public override int Method1(int x,int y, out ConcurrentDictionary<string,int> dictionary)
{
  if(dictionary.IsEmpty)
  {
   do something
  }
}
```

The error message i got is "use of unassigned out parameter dictionary". And I need to preserve the content of dictionary throughout the codes.  Appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think "out" means?
"out" is a bit like "ref".  "ref" and "out" work with .NET [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t63sy5hs.aspx). "ref" indicates that the method can change the object the variable references. i.e. change what piece of memory the variable is pointing to.  "out" indicates that it is expected that the method will define what object the variable references.

i.e. with out parameters you must instantiate the instance of the parameter within the method

e.g

```
public override int Method1(int x,int y, out ConcurrentDictionary<string,int> dictionary)
{
    dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,int>();
    // It doesn't make sense to check if it is empty here as it will always be empty
    // if(dictionary.IsEmpty)
    //  {
```

Comment: "Out means that the parameter is returned from the method". No. You should rephrase that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `dictionary` is an `out` parameter, you have to guarantee that `dictionary` is assigned to by the time `Method1` finishes. If you don't want to change `dictionary`, you could just assign it to itself.